# google analytics 4 api dimension restricting metrics

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

i'm trying to get the following metrics

```
  new Metric { Name = "sessions" },
            new Metric { Name = "engagedSessions" },
            new Metric { Name = "conversions" },
            new Metric { Name = "activeUsers" }
```

for the following dimensions

```
            new Dimension { Name = "deviceCategory" },
            new Dimension { Name = "date" },
            new Dimension { Name = "country" },
            new Dimension { Name = "city" },
            new Dimension { Name = "firstUserCampaignId" },
            new Dimension { Name = "firstUserCampaignName" },
            new Dimension { Name = "firstUserSource" },
            new Dimension { Name = "firstUserMedium" }
```

When I query the api for just one day, without dimensions, let's say 2023-09-01, then I get the right metrics, but with dimensions much lower or no value.

I'd expect to see the same number just broken down by dimensions, even if they are not set.

Can I achieve this anyhow, as I need all this data but for all users, not reduced if the metric does not exist in the dimension?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is the threshold issue

[GA4 document about threshold](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630?hl=en&sjid=15229051819851326336-AP)

As you can see. Some of the metric is related to `User`.
And if you break into too many level of dimension. If the number is lower than around 30-50(No accurate number from Google). Then GA4 will just hide the number

That's said:

country , 100 users

---

country, city a, 80 users

country, city b, 15 users

country, city c, 5 users

---

The outcome is very like to be only

country, city a, 80 users

because city b, city c rows encounter the `thresholds` issue

---

If you want to escape from `thresholds`. Just remove the metric and dimension related to `User`